# How to custom ListView android

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I would like to know , if it's possible , if i can have a custom ListView which looks like an array.
And if it's possible , how i begin ? i create other layout? listeview ?
I put the link of the mockup of the listView.
I hope that you understand my question (it's not to hard =))

Link of the image :  [Click here](http://www.casimages.com/img.php?i=13111802384771909.png)

Of course, at the end, i will get data with webservice (but it's ok for me =))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weolcome to SO, 
of course it is possible to create your own ListView. You just have to implement a so called `custom ArrayAdapter` and a Layout which would represent a row in your ListView.
Have a look at this great Site, with a tutorial with exactly what you are looking for-.

[VOGELLA TUTORIAL](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Do not be scared of the long code, after the first tries it should be very clear what to do!

Comment: Could you please accept it as right answer and give a upvote?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe what you're looking for

http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/